# Как запустить скрипт Python, через другой скрипт, и при этом передать данные с одного на другой?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-3.7, subprocess

Моя программа состоит из двух скриптов Python: Main.py - основной скрипт с которого запускается второстепенный, и Script.py - второстепенный скрипт, в котором выполняется действие программы.

Вот код:

Main.py:

```
import sys
import subprocess
from subprocess import Popen
import psutil
import time

def Start():
    InPutSign = input("Введите символ, фразу или набор символов: ")
    Time = input("Время в секундах: ")

    proc = subprocess.Popen([sys.executable, "Script.py"])
    time.sleep(Time)
    proc.kill()

while True:
    Start()
```

Script.py:

```
while True:
    print(Sign)
```

Мне нужно чтобы данные в переменной `InPutSign` (в Main.py) передавались в Script.py в переменную `Sign`.

Вопрос: Как это сделать? (меня устроит любой способ)

Comment: sockets........

Comment: с помощью параметра командной строки

Comment: Можно передавать аргументы скриптам точно так же, как и в терминале `python script.py arg_1 arg_2`. Но вы уверены, что вам надо именно это? Может быть можно импортировать один из скриптов как модуль в другой?